# searching lucene index file

Tags: java, search, lucene

trying to understand better way of using

> writer.forceMerge(int)

and when to use it. I am working on Lucene (5.4.1 version) in order to generate an index file am using writer.forceMerge(1) to merge segments, which I guess creates segments_2 file in index. On the other hand, while i am trying to read it which throwing `indexRepositoryException: cannot instantiate the reader: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.../segments (No such file or directory)`. I am trying to figure out the issue whether this is related to forceMerge(1) or not ? I've gone through few documents which are available online, but unable to get the expected solution.

Comment: Well, in general, the best way to use `forceMerge` is to *not* use it at all, and just let your MergePolicy do it's job.  If you do need to call it, I probably wouldn't force it to merge down to a single segment by passing it a `1`.

Comment: I am generating an static index file which won't get updated or deleted, so i was using forceMerge(1) as recommended by Lucene docs. @femtoRgon

Comment: The same code is working in my local ( windows) , but while creating instance of reader from initServlet after deploying code in servers, we are getting below exception. i am still trying to understand what might be the problem. Env/localhost-startStop-1:INFO:err org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in MMapDirectory@/../apache-tomcat-7.0.57/.../indexFile lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@2b326aee: files: [] @femtoRgon